# C#: How to check if drop down item from ToolStripMenuItem is checked

Tags: c#, winforms

I created a drop down menu using following code

```
foreach (string name in Enum.GetNames(enumeratieType))
{
    if (name != "NN")
    {
        ToolStripMenuItem it = (ToolStripMenuItem)item.DropDownItems.Add(name);
        it.Checked = true;
        it.CheckOnClick = true;
    }
}
```

I can't find a way to check if for example the first item is checked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access it by index or name. When you create it:

```
ToolStripMenuItem it = ...
it.Name = name;
```

Then to get it:

```
var menuitem = item.DropDownItems.DropDownItems["name you want"];
```

Comment: Thanks, I casted menuitem to a ToolStripMenuItem object so I was able to use the checked property. 

`var menuitem2 = itemT.DropDownItems["luxe"];
            ToolStripMenuItem menuitem3 = (ToolStripMenuItem) menuitem2;
            bool checkedItem = menuitem3.Checked;`